# JSON & URL = How to parse?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Regards to all!
I wanted to ask you, **how to parse JSON data from the link?**
For example, I have a task, based on this JSON =>
(https://www.link-elearning.com/linkdl/coursefiles/1470/quiz.json) **to make a quiz!**
I have an idea, I know how I'm going to do it!
But, what is not clear to me, how can I PASS all the data from the given link?

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khFfc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. Wouldn't you use AJAX to GET data from your endpoint? Using jQuery you'd get your JSON:

```
jQuery.get( "https://www.link-elearning.com/linkdl/coursefiles/1470/quiz.json", function( data ) {
  jQuery("#questionDiv").text(dta.quiz.q1.question);
// iterate through your questions. Foe each question iterate through your options.
});
```

Comment: Ty @Dev, thats it! ♥